# The s2i build --as-dockerfile command get a warning

Tags: openshift, podman, s2i

im using **openshift local** on wmware, when run this command

> ```
> s2i build test/test-app/ s2i-do288-httpd s2i-sample-app \
>
> --as-dockerfile ~/s2i-sample-app/Containerfile
> ```

get this warning

> WARNING: could not inspect the builder image for labels: reading
> manifest latest in docker.io/library/s2i-do288-httpd: requested access
> to the resource is denied

doing a inspect of my generated Containerfile **~/s2i-sample-app/Containerfile**:

> FROM docker.io/library/s2i-do288-httpd

when it should be:

> FROM s2i-do288-httpd

all of this results in an error when I run

podman build........because it can't find the right image

NB. image s2i-do288-httpd was created by

1. s2i create
2. podman build